# Python 3.5 - Anaconda 4.2 x64 on W7 - unable to use openpyxl (library not loaded)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, installation, anaconda, openpyxl

I'm unable to use `openpyxl` after installing Anaconda 4.2 x64 with Python 3.5.
At the beginning of my notebook, I put this line:

```
.....
from openpyxl import load_workbook
MyFile = 'c:\\Myfile.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = MyFile)
```

or

```
import openpyxl as opxl
MyFile = 'c:\\Myfile.xlsx'
wb = opxl.load_workbook(filename = MyFile)
```

Every time, I get this message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b8f87c92e96e> in <module>()
      8 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
      9 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---> 10 from openpyxl import load_workbook

D:\Users\toto\Documents\Python Scripts\openpyxl.py in <module>()
      8 
      9 fichier_source = 'IRIS_FORMATION.xlsx'
---> 10 wb = load_workbook(fichier_source, data_only = True)
     11 ws = wb.active
     12 print("Chargement de " + fichier_source)

NameError: name 'load_workbook' is not defined
```

I've updated the installation then I made a brand new installation (after removing all the .directories), I've checked the PATH variable.
I always have the same message on 2 different PC but on my personal PC (with Windows 10), it works fine!
But I have to install Anaconda on other PC for my colleagues, so I have to find the reason of this error.
I've compared the PATH variables (on the W10 PC and on the other) => same information.
I've updated the openpyxl with conda =>ok, I got the 2.4.0 version, I've tried to updated then with pip => I got a message saying that openpyxl is already updated...

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Don't name your script `openpyxl.py`, you're confusing Python's import mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not my script.I don't have a file named fichier_source = 'IRIS_FORMATION.xlsx' nor 'openpyxl.py'. My notebook is named "MDM_xxxx.ipynb". I don't know from where it comes, so I don't understand the error message and I can't correct the error.... I get the same error and the error message on a new PC just by installing Anaconda 4.2 (not my PC, with no personal configuration ;-).....

Comment: but your comment give me an idea : it seems that the openpyxl is not seen as a library and is not loaded (that was my first idea). But why?